# Did the Borg collective have an insignia?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-insignias

In some Star Trek games and other expanded-universe material, the Borg paired with the insignia seen in TNG's "Descent" episodes.

[image]

However, were those Borg actually part of the collective proper, or somehow isolated by Lore to use for his own ends?  If the latter, was the insignia then something of Lore's design or properly Borg?  I don't recall seeing that insignia on other TNG or VOY episodes.

Comment: I don't have photos to confirm, but I'm pretty sure it was seen around the ship in *Q, Who?*

Comment: I definitely think that @DVK 's answer is worthy of acceptance.

Comment: I can't help but notice how similar this symbol is to the Narada, Romulan ship from Star Trek 2009

Comment: This seems to be missing an acceptance :-)

Answer (score 17):

As eidylon noted, the insignia was NOT a Lore thing - it first appeared in "Q, Who", designed by Rick Sternbach.

> The insignia appears at about 35:00 in the episode, to the left of Commander Riker as the away team walks into the Borg nursery.
>   (source: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29#cite_ref-n1_0-0))

[image: screenshot from TNG episode showing the insignia on the wall next to Data and Riker]

The 1992 TNG trading card ([Inaugural Edition 82-A](http://www.comiccollectorlive.com/LiveData/SaleItem.aspx?id=a81ec12f-8ca4-4c6f-ba21-f81bb23fc2f3)) has a card for the Borg insignia with the following description,

> *"Resembling a great red claw over a background of circuitry, the symbol of the Borg is as mysterious as the race it represents. The
>   Borg symbol may possibly define an amalgam of living tissue with
>   computer circuits, as the Borg are believed to be a race of cybernetic
>   organisms..."*

[image: "Symbol of the Borg" trading card]

Comment: *"Believed to be"* ??

Comment: @ThePopMachine: ***DATA:** Sir, The Captain has been altered by the Borg. **RIKER:** Altered? **WORF:** He IS a Borg!*